# How do I check IIS status and uptime?

Tags: powershell, iis, wmi, wmic

I'm trying to use either a wmic or powershell command to check the state of IIS (if it's running or not) and uptime.

To check the state I've used the wmic command:

```
wmic path Win32_Service where Name='IISADMIN' get State
```

but I've read that the IISADMIN service is not necessary for later versions of IIS to be running.

Is there another service I can check for this purpose or another method I can use to get this information?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this on a per App Pool basis, using Get-Process and WMI:

```
Get-Process w3wp | % {
$thepid = $_.Id
$wmiProc = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessID = '$thepid'"
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    CommandLine = $wmiProc.CommandLine
    StartTime = $_.StartTime
    }
}
```

The command line property will help you figure out what App Pool you're looking at.